# TortoiseGit: Push to new remote branch

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I've set up a project to use TeamCity and Git, and I'd like to use TeamCity's new [Branch Remote Run feature](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Branch+Remote+Run+Trigger).  The way this work is to push your working directory to a remote branch that the TeamCity build is watching, e.g.:

```
git push origin +HEAD:remote-run/my_feature
```

What I *think* this is saying is "push `HEAD` to the remote branch `remote-run/my_feature` in the `origin` repository, creating it if necessary" (I would welcome clarification if that's even slightly incorrect).

My problem is that I'm using TortoiseGit with MSysGit set up to use PuTTY.  This is working fine, but it means I can't drop into Git Bash and issue the command through the command-line as Git Bash relies on OpenSSH.  I'm not up for re-installing MSysGit (and potentially TortoiseGit too).

So, what's the magical set of checkboxes and textboxes to get TortoiseGit to run a push as described above?

Comment: You can set the windows env variable `GIT_SSH` to point to plink.exe and msysgit will use pageant. [Walkthrough](http://my.afterdawn.com/agent_007/blog_entry.cfm/2909/git_and_cygwin)

Comment: That already seems to be the case: Issuing `$env:GIT_SSH` in PowerShell gives `C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoisePlink.exe`

Comment: Oops, it helps if Pageant is running and has my keys loaded, I guess :-)  Please could you post your comment as an answer and I'll upvote and accept.

Comment: Correction: the + at the front of the refspec means "push this, even if it's not a fast-forward", which means you can overwrite history on the remote. If it's just a dedicated build branch, it's probably no problem, but just be aware.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Stewart; that's exactly the sort of thing that would have bitten me eventually, I'm sure (and I like to understand what it is I'm doing rather than issuing commands blindly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure pageant is running and has your key loaded... Then you can set the windows env variable `GIT_SSH` to point to plink.exe and msysgit will use pageant. [Link to walkthrough](http://my.afterdawn.com/agent_007/blog_entry.cfm/2909/git_and_cygwin)